# How to cut out pauses and unneeded places from video in Adobe Premiere?

Tags: premiere

I have a long video and wish to cut pauses and unneeded places from it. Currently I know how to select mark ins and mark outs

[image]

Unfortunately, this does not allow to have multiple ins and outs in single clip.

If I cut multiple clips from one video, then will probably loose a sequence.

How to accomplish the task?

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "If I cut multiple clips from one video, then will probably loose a sequence."?

Comment: See my comments to your answer.

Comment: Did eLouais and my answers and comments solve your problem? Or do you need additional assistance on that issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a **sequence**. If you're not familiar with video codecs, the easiest way to do so is to right-click on your clip in the project panel and select **New sequence from clip ...**, which will create a sequence using the resolution and framerate from your clip.

Once you've created the sequence, it should appear as a timeline in the lower right area of your screen. If you have not yet set an in- and outpoint, your video will be in the sequence as a whole. Make sure to delete that (right-click on the video in the timeline and select **Clear**), so that you get an empty timeline to start with.

Then you can start putting your video together. Set the in- and outpoint for the first scene from your video that you want to use and then **drag** the clip from the project panel into the timeline (alternatively, you can push **insert** (shortcut <kbd>,</kbd>) or **overwrite** (shortcut <kbd>.</kbd>)). Move on to the next scene in your video, again set in- and outpoint and insert the clip into the timeline, and so on.

Once you have everything arranged in your sequence, you can export the sequence as a whole via **File** -> **Export** -> **Media ...**.

Comment: Suppose I have 100 scenes in the video. Suppose I put 95 of them. Then I found that I have extra scene between previous scenes No. 45 no 46. Suppose scenes are very similar and it is hard to identify them by eye. How do I find where to put my new scene in timeline?

Comment: It will be better if I was able to mark multiple ins and outs in the whole video.

Comment: Well that's just not possible, you can always have but one in- and one outpoint. However, you could use **markers** to mark specific parts instead. Simply press **F** to add a marker at the current position. You can do this in the source monitor as well as in the sequence timeline.
To find specific parts of your source clip in the timeline and vice versa, you can use a technique called **Match Frame**. While the timeline is focused (i.e. there's a yellow outline around it), press F to find the frame that is currently showing in the program panel in the source panel. TBC

Comment: This will show you which where the clip in the timeline came from. If you want to find out if you have already used a specific part of your source clip, make sure the source monitor is focused and press **Shift + R** (Reverse Match Frame). If the current frame is already present in the timeline, this will show you where it is. If nothing happens, it means that you haven't used that part of the video yet.

Comment: What you do to 'mark' the scene is to add comments. Thats how all the other editors do it. Just move the playhead where you want it and hit 'M'

Comment: @eLouai Thanks for repeating what I mentioned above ;) Although I just noticed I accidentally wrote F instead of M o.o

Comment: Ahh Gin-San, my biggest issue in life, I see large block of text and my mind fogs up. Sorry about that. Did not read all the comments. It's one of my failings :). I appreciate and read a lot of your answers in other sections, really liked them and enjoyed your expertise :)

Comment: No hard feelings, I didn't mean to be mean °ω° I did write the wrong shortcut, so it's good you cleared that up!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have multiple marks in and out on clip.

What you would do is you would mark a clip and drop it in a sequence (the timeline).
Mark another clip and drop it in the timeline. Son on and so forth.

The issue you would have is the sound just clips as it jumps from clip to clip in the sequence. The quickest way to fix that is just right click in the timeline on two clips that are joined and you get the option to add a transition. Adding the default tranistion fades/overlapes the sound of the two tracks. Also it does the same to the video.

If you want to prevent the video from doing a crossfade, what I do is first right click on the clip on the timeline and 'unlink' so the audio and video is not linked and THEN I do the transistion on the audio only.

Hope that helps.

GL

Comment: Unlinking audio and video is a terrible idea with so many clips and some parts that may or may not be inserted into the timeline at some point. Simply press CTRL + SHIFT + D, that will only add transitions to your audio, leaving the video unaltered

Comment: Aaaahhh, where have you been .... CTRL + SHIFT + D, would have saved me a TON of work. Lifesaver. *Me glued to the screen, realizing the hours of work this little key stroke is going to save me and drolling* :)

Comment: Things like that happen to me all the time ^^' I guess that's the downside of learning a new technique; realising you've been wasting time °ω°